# Issue with CiviMail reports after upgrade to 5.19.0

Tags: wordpress, civimail

I upgraded to 5.19.0 and noticed that every report for completed mailings listed on the Find Mailings screen is now showing this message in the Delivery Summary section:

```
Delivery has not yet begun for this mailing. If the scheduled delivery date and time is past, ask the system administrator or technical support contact for your site to verify that the automated mailer task ('cron job') is running - and how frequently.
```

Despite this, the reports still show the Click-through Summary and other sections.

I see this issue on both my production and development systems. I tried clearing cache. Other CiviMail reports (from the Reports tab) seem to be correct.

CiviCRM 5.19.0
Wordpress 5.2.4
PHP 7.2.21
MySQL 5.7.23

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug. If you turn on "Enable Debugging" at Administer - System Settings - Debugging it might give more info since I think I see similar on the public demo but since it doesn't have real mail enabled I'm not sure. If you do see warnings when you turn that on I'd say you should report it at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/mail/issues

Comment: See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/mail/issues/56

Comment: Thanks, I followed up on https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/mail/issues/56.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is fixed with https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15780. It will be hopefully included in a point release that should come out soon for 5.19

Comment: That does solve my issue. Thanks.