# Mailing summary doesn't display - says that mailing not complete

Tags: civimail

Updated to CiviCRM 5.19 - ran one of our biweekly mailings last night and I wanted to check the open count.  But Civi says that the mailing isn't completed,[image]
even though it shows on the mailing summary that it completed at 5:45 AM.[image]

Does anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33630/issue-with-civimail-reports-after-upgrade-to-5-19-0. But I see you've posted a lab ticket -  thanks for doing that: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/mail/issues/56

Answer (score 2):

@logan Bear i would recommend you upgrade to 5.19.1 It has just come out and should include this PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15779 which should resolve your issue